# How to print key value properties from array with condition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

html

```
  <p id="demo"></p>
```

js

```
const kids = [
{ name: 'fluffy', age: 5 },
{ name: 'archimedes', age: 9 },
{ name: 'meowth', age: 3 },
{ name: 'gertrude', age: 4 },
{ name: 'penelope', age: 7}
];

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xxx;
```

I want to print inside the `p` the name and age to display name of kids aged 5 and higher

I have also done a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rvxjg3f3/)

Comment: if your wanna print the name of kids aged 5 and higher, then it is not 'key value pairs'. It is values of the properties.

Comment: updated @CharlieNg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *filter* an array based on your condition via [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=example). And then you can *map* the array elements to their string representations via [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example):

```js
const kids = [
  { name: 'fluffy', age: 5 },
  { name: 'archimedes', age: 9 },
  { name: 'meowth', age: 3 },
  { name: 'gertrude', age: 4 },
  { name: 'penelope', age: 7}
];

// Filter kids array by given condition:
let selection = kids.filter(kid => kid.age >= 5);

// Map selected kids to strings:
let strings = selection.map(({name, age}) => `${name}, ${age} years old`);

// Concatenate strings for output:
document.getElementById('demo').textContent = strings.join('; ');
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: thank you! `=>` what does this do ? does it mean its a child of kid. just trying to understand that part @le_m

Comment: @ZenaMesfin The arrow in JavaScript has nothing to do with object -> child access etc. It produces an [arrow function](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/5007/arrow-functions). You can think of it as a shortcut for `kids.filter(function (kid) { return kid.age >= 5; });`

Answer (score 1):

You can first filter and then iterate over filtered array. So use `Array#filter` and `Array#forEach`

```js
const kids = [{
    name: 'fluffy',
    age: 5
  },
  {
    name: 'archimedes',
    age: 9
  },
  {
    name: 'meowth',
    age: 3
  },
  {
    name: 'gertrude',
    age: 4
  },
  {
    name: 'penelope',
    age: 7
  }
];
var filteredKids = kids.filter(x => x.age>=5);
var ans="";
filteredKids.forEach((v,i) => ans+= 'name:'+v.name+', age:'+v.age+' ');
//console.log(ans);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ans;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```